# Application have Only BroadcastReceiver is not working

Tags: android

I have only one CallBroadcastReceiver which extends BroadcastReceiver and a menifest where its declared.

Still its not showing the Toast while I am placing a outgoing call.
Can you please help?

its showing

```
[2016-02-27 10:02:20 - OnlyReciever] No Launcher activity found!
[2016-02-27 10:02:20 - OnlyReciever] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

Code Below -

CallBroadcastReceiver.class

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * @author Cosmos
 *
 */
public class CallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public CallBroadcastReceiver() {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ind.example.onlyreciever"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="22"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver 
            android:name="ind.example.onlyreciever.CallBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You don't need any activity in this project, is it so?

Comment: @astuter yes, I think so...I just need to show a toast msg whenever a outgoing call gets initiated. Do I need an activity for this ?

Comment: @astuter that can be done. But I think that's not needed. check out this link [Example of App without mainActivity] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htU_Rd-DW2U)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Android 3.1 and higher,**

You have to launch one of your activities to get your app out of stopped state before any manifest-registered BroadcastReceiver will work, as detailed in the [3.1 release notes](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols).

When the app is first installed or manually force-closed, it is in "stopped state". In this state, only broadcast intents with the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag will reach your broadcast receivers; this flag is not included in the default system broadcasts, so the app cannot receive them in the stopped state.

Note that "stopped state" is tracked by the package manager and is not the same as "application not running". Once the app is out of stopped state, it will remain so even if you reboot your device and your app is not running.

Comment: ok.. if I use activity to register it first time will it always keep running ?

Comment: what is your view on this ?

Comment: @Bharat that example in the video is targetting froyo

Comment: `For Android 3.1 and higher` source?

Comment: froyo is an old version of android or different operating System? I tried googling ... could not find anything

Comment: Could you give more explanations/sources for this answer ?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html check it

Comment: search for this... "how to use broadcast receiver without service and activity in android" on google you will find many of them..

Comment: All right, I took the liberty to post an edit to include the relevant information