# Restart fourground service when System Processer Killed

Tags: android

Not Restart of Foreground service  While System Killed or user forcefully closed , I tried OnstartCommand Method Return Sticky Intent and ,  calling start service through broadcast receiver in ondestory method but service not recreated or started

```
  @Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.lon.loanonmind.loanonmind.MyService");
    intent.setClass(this, LocationServices.class);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    Log.d("KIll","Service Killed");

}


@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.lon.loanonmind.loanonmind.MyService");
    intent.setClass(this, LocationServices.class);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    Log.d("KIll","Service Killed");

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.lon.loanonmind.loanonmind.MyService");
    intent.setClass(this, LocationServices.class);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    super.onDestroy();


}
```

//return statement of onstart command
 return START_STICKY;

Comment: there must be something wrong with your code .  `return START_STICKY;` will do the job.

Comment: Please explain better what exactly is your problem.

Comment: I will suggest you to read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647788/service-is-not-running-always-even-after-i-have-used-start-sticky

Answer (score 0):

Please use Alarm Service for restart your services

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.lon.loanonmind.loanonmind.MyService");
intent.setClass(this, LocationServices.class);   
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent , 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(intent );
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),5000, pintent);
```